# How to add an AWS Amplify application as subdomain for domain hosted in AWS Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-amplify

I have an main domain in hosted in Route 53. I want to add a subdomain to it. Like business.mainwebsite.com . I have an amplify application which i want to add there.
I tried making cname in route53 and gave cname value as amplify link. But it is redirecting it to main website only.

Answer (score 3):

Two steps:

1. Remove *.mainwebsite.com from already hosted at cloudfront.
2. Follow this, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-amazon-route-53.html

Answer (score 1):

Amplify can manage that for you without going to Route53, as long as you have **mainwebsite.com** registered in Route 53. In the Amplify console be sure to modify the default sub-domain to **business**, going with your example.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-amazon-route-53.html

Comment: my main domain website is on s3 and subdomain on amplify. When i am adding subdomain from amplify domain management console, its showing that one or more cname mentioned is already associated with another resource.